# python regex search stop on find \n caracter

Tags: python, regex

i need to scrape data from json string, my current code is :

```
import re
>>> output = """
... Uploading file 'ex4-to-mq4-ps-decompiler.mp4'...
... Progress:    13.29 Mbps, 3703728 / 3703084 (100.017%) ETA       0s
... Upload successful! Video ID: tZ5xaRLhljc
... Video added to playlist 'decompile mql4' (PL2Q1nwGTMjdeAsBn6mcQ7KuFo6K7_g8_L)
... Video added to playlist 'decompile ex4' (PL2Q1nwGTMjdffMBkc6L4r6SeXnjz7eUiP)
... """
re.search("Video ID: (.+)", output, re.S).group(1)

>>> re.search("Video ID: (.+)?", output, re.S).group(1)
"tZ5xaRLhljc\nVideo added to playlist 'decompile mql4' (PL2Q1nwGTMjdeAsBn6mcQ7KuFo6K7_g8_L)\nVideo added to playlist 'decompile ex4' (PL2
```

i need extract only id of video `tZ5xaRLhljc`
how i can do this ?

Comment: Your first solution works, remove `re.S` only. `re.search("Video ID: (.+)", output).group(1)`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`re.S` is `re.DOTALL` which makes `.` match the newline `\n` character. If you remove it, `.` will not longer match newlines and your code will work. Perhaps a more safe solution

```
re.search(r"Video ID: (\w+)", output).group(1)
```

where `\w` matches all "word" characters (i.e. non-whitespace).

Answer (score 2):

Try this:

```
re.search("Video ID: (.+)\n", output).group(1)
```